# Knology email user not receiving PHP mailer?

Tags: phpmailer, mailer

I have a PHP mailer that sends out auto emails to confirm registration and alerts when the customer's online number is pinged.

I have only one customer complaining about not receiving alert emails to her Knology account. She can receive the registration confirmation, but not an alert email.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Is it in her spam folder?  What exactly gets put in spam varies both by how much the recipient's email provider trusts your IP address, and by the content of the email.

Comment: No, she's checked spam and contacted tech support from her email carrier. I'm wondering if the possibility could be in her phone not processing the scan by her phone which prompts the email.

Comment: You need to check your mail server's outbound mail logs.

Comment: I checked the outbound mail logs and am only seeing the registration confirmation, not the alert emails like I stated. Could it be the phone not prompting the email?